# Meta в HTML5

Tags: html, html5

Здраствуйте!

В общем, меня интересует **одна команда в html5**. Описание очень простое. Вроде в этой строке кода может храниться какой-либо документ, видео или картинка и др. Мне не понятно, как в команду `<meta content=" . . . ">` засунуть видео, картинку или документ. Если это не возможно, тогда просто скажите, что вообще можно делать с этим кодом.

Спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метаданные - это информация о данных документа. Пример метаданных: автор документа, время создания документа, время последней модификации, кодировка документа и т.д.

Подробнее http://www.wisdomweb.ru/HTML5d/html5_meta.php